# Oracle ORA -932 expected Number got CHAR

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am running the following query and can't seem to figure out where the error is-

```
select  case when month>=7 then substr(year,3,2)|| '/'||TO_NUMBER( substr(year,3,2))+1
 else to_number(substr(year,3,2))-1 || '/'|| substr(year,3,2) end as fiscal_year
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT to_Char(extract( year from date)) as year,
 extract( month from date)as MONTH  FROM TABLE )
```

I want to convert year to fiscal year like 19/20, 20/21 etc

Comment: Your fiscal year starts in July? Right now you are in fiscal year 20/21, from July in 21/22?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [operator precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Operators.html#GUID-FEF44762-F45C-41D9-B380-F6A61AD25338) means the string concatenation is happening before the addition; this expression:

```
substr(year,3,2)|| '/'||TO_NUMBER( substr(year,3,2))+1
```

is evaluated as

```
substr(year,3,2)|| '/'||TO_NUMBER( substr(year,3,2))
```

and *then* it tries to add 1 to that string result. Hence the error you get.

You can add parentheses to make it add 1 to the year number before then concatenating that:

```
substr(year,3,2)|| '/'|| (TO_NUMBER( substr(year,3,2))+1)
```

You could also do this without so much string manipulation:

```
select case when extract (month from your_date) >= 7 then
    to_char(your_date, 'YY') || '/' || to_char(add_months(your_date, 12), 'YY')
  else
    to_char(add_months(your_date, -12), 'YY') || '/' || to_char(your_date, 'YY')
  end as fiscal_year
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT trunc(your_date, 'MM') as your_date
  FROM your_table
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8eef30e87c5646b703ddb38ac7ff2d5)

and there are other options, of course.